# How to create field instance with display none programmatically

Tags: entities

I tried to create some fields and field instance programmatically in .install file.

And I need to set a specail field instance with display none.

I have google, but got nothing.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not very clear.

What do you mean "display none"?

- Make your field in the .install file.
- Add a CSS file to your module info file`files[]=mymodule.css`
- in the CSS file of your module `.field-myfield {display:none;}`.
- clear your drupal cache

**EDIT**

I think you probably want to look at [Field Permissions module](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions).

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: "display none" is mean in the entity "MANAGE DISPLAY" page config the field "FORMAT" with the value "<Hidden>".

Comment: Field instance settings per content type can be Exported and managed in code when using the Features module. see drupal.org/project/features. Export the field to a Feature -- and examine how it sets up the `$field_config` and `$field_instance_config` in `mymodule.features.field.inc`